# Issue on using Autolayout with iAd

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, iad, uistoryboard

I'm building an app that supports both portrait and landscape orientations and am using autolayout to make the process simpler. I have placed an `AdBannerView` at the bottom and have pinned the bottom space to superview. Here are my screens in Portrait and Landscape orientations:

**Portrait:**

[image: Portrait Mode]

**Landscape:**

[image: Landscape Mode]

The behaviour is as expected in portrait mode. However, in landscape mode I am getting some whitespace below the AdBannerView. What is the reason for this and how do I get rid of it? Do I need to write additional code to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IOS 6 no need to worry about iAd orientation check this link.

> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

```
if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) {
        _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
    } else {
        _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way I can achieve this by using autolayout alone and without needing to write any additional code?